# Вид предложения 2

Tags: недопустимая-метка

Почему данное предложение:
Ему вдруг стало жалко и дома, который развалится, и сада, который запустится. - . Сложноподчиненное предложение с параллельным подчинением придаточных частей, а не Сложноподчиненное предложение с однородным подчинением придаточных частей.

Comment: Посетите страницу "как задавать вопросы"!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Почему** данное предложение:
>   *Ему вдруг стало жалко и дома, который развалится, и сада, который запустится.* - Сложноподчиненное предложение с параллельным
>   подчинением придаточных частей...

*Ему вдруг стало жалко и **дома** (какого?), который развалится, и **сада** (какого?), который запустится.*

-- **придаточные одного типа относятся** **к разным членам предложения главной части.**

======

Из Литневской (http://gramota.ru/book/litnevskaya.php?part5.htm#423 ):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

======

В сложноподчинённых же предложениях **с однородным подчинением** придаточные предложения являются однотипными и относятся или **к одному и тому же члену главного предложения**, или ко всему главному предложению в целом.

Это не наш случай.